# How to send CTRL+c special char to interactive bash over tcp socket?

Tags: bash, signals, netcat, reverse-proxy

I use interactive `bash` shell over TCP network, but can't figure out how to send CTRL+c sequence to the remote `bash`.

I first run `netcat` instance (this is where I interact with remote bash):

```
nc -nvlp 8000
```

Then, from the remote I run (for simplicity, I use localhost so you can try it out locally in another terminal):

```
bash -i >& /dev/tcp/localhost/8000 0>&1
```

---

Now, in the netcat terminal the interactive bash appeared and I can send commands to it, which get executed and the result is shown.

What I didn't figure out yet, is how to propagate CTRL+c sequence to the remote bash and ignore it within the `netcat` process.

---

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
nc -nvlp 8000 & trap "printf '\003' >/proc/$!/fd/0" INT; fg; trap 0 INT
```

This starts `netcat` in the background, sets up `trap`, which prints end-of-file sequence (`0x03`) to the stdin of the netcat if `SIGINT` is received.

Then, using the `fg` command, the `netcat` process is brought to the foreground so that the interactive session can begin. Executing commands works just fine, but when I use CTRL+c sequence, `netcat` dies with `130` return code, printing nothing in either the `netcat`, nor the `bash` terminal.

The final trap resets the `SIGINT` handler.

The `bash` process ends with `0` return code, indicating success.

Any ideas, how this could be done?

Comment: You cannot do that. Instead of netcat or /dev/tcp you'll have to use something that allocates a pty on the remote side and run bash in it. By the time you got all that, you've reinvented ssh ;-)

Comment: The shell (or in general any program which reads the terminal in "cooked" mode) never actually reads a Control-C character; what happens is that the terminal driver sees the Control-C and sends a *signal* to the shell. That's why @UncleBilly said that you need to allocate a pseudoterminal...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but you can background the netcat process (hit CTRL+Z), type `stty raw -echo` and then resume the process. Now it should work.